# Express $F(n,k)$ through Stirling Numbers if ...

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Express $F(n,k)$ through Stirling Numbers if

> $1)\ F(n,k)$ represents the number of sequences $a_1,..., a_n$ of
>   natural numbers not surpassing the number $k$.
>
> $2)$ The first occurrence of the number $i$ happens before the first
>   occurrence of the number $i +1$.
>
> $3)$ Each of the numbers $1,..,k$ appears at least one time.

I would like some help with this. For sure the numbers $1, ...,k$ are our elements and point $3)$ seems to suggest the application of Stirling Number of the 2nd Kind, but I don't understand what $2)$ means and don't know how to put the $3$ requirements together.

For instance if I put $F(2,1)$ we would have $2$ sequences of natural numbers not surpassing $1$. My guess is that the sequences would be

$(1),\ (1,1)$

Now for $F(2,2)$ we have $2$ sequences of natural numbers not surpassing $2$:

$(1), (1,2)$

For $F(3,2)$

$(1),\ (1,1),\ (1,2)$

I'm assuming the requirement $2)$ is for each sequence, that is for $F(3,2)$ the sequence $(2,1)$ and $2$ are not allowed (the first $2$ in a sequence has to appear after the first $1$).

In any case, the approach I followed doesn't seem to give any clue about how to express this function through Stirling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The third condition says that you’re partitioning $[n]$ into exactly $k$ parts, one for each the numbers $1,\ldots,k$: the $i$-th part is the set of positions in which $i$ appears. The second condition says in effect that if you have a partition of $[n]$ into $k$ parts, and the minimum elements of the parts are $m_1<m_2<\ldots<m_k$, then the part with minimum $m_i$ must be the part that contains the element $i$ of $[k]$. Thus, each partition of $[n]$ into $k$ parts determines a unique sequence.

Comment: Then, as far as I understand, the third condition means we can partition $n$ into exactly $k$ parts in $S(n,k)$. But since the numbers $1,..,k$ are distinguishable, we have to account for the permutation between themselves. So from the third condition we have $k!S(n,k)$ partitions.  I didn't quite get the hint about the second condition ):

Comment: @Jazz: No, the third condition just tells you that you want partitions into exactly $k$ parts; without the third condition you might have partitions into fewer than $k$ parts. The second condition is what tells you that you *don’t* have to account for permutations of the parts: the correct permutation is completely determined by the numbers $m_1,\ldots,m_k$. The part that contains $1$ *must* be the part for the element $1$ of $[k]$. The part with the next smallest minimum *must* be the part for the element $2$ of $[k]$. And so on.

Comment: I think I got it. Can I elaborate a bit?
Let have $k$ classes enumerated from $1$ to $k$, and objects $a_1, ..., a_n$. From the third condition none of the boxes has to be empty and from the second condition we have the arrangement of boxes is fixed (they don't permute among themselves). From this it follows that the number $F(n,k)$ is equal to $S(n,k)$.

Comment: @Jazz: Yes, that’s exactly right. The boxes have to go in order of their least elements.

Comment: I appreciate your help (:, Thanks!!

Comment: @Jazz: You’re welcome!