# Stirling number of the second kind solution from another recurrence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I have been trying to work out [this strling number problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923107/on-stirling-number/2923200#2923200) using some other recurrence which I had worked on before
$P_{n,k}=1 + P_{n-1,k-1}+ P_{n-1,k}$.
One solution was... 
$$P_{n, k}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}{n \choose j} -->(1)$$

Now I'm trying to apply this solution to find a solution to Stirling number of the second kind recurrence( which I already found in Wiki)
$$S_{n,k}=S_{n-1,k-1} + kS_{n-1,k}->(2)$$
 like this.
$$P_{n,k}=1 + P_{n-1,k-1}+ P_{n-1,k}$$
$$=>kP_{n,k}=k + kP_{n-1,k-1}+ kP_{n-1,k}$$
$$=>kP_{n,k} - k= P_{n-1,k-1}+ (k-1)P_{n-1,k-1} + kP_{n-1,k}$$
$$=>kP_{n,k} - k - (k-1)P_{n-1,k-1}= P_{n-1,k-1} + kP_{n-1,k}$$

Now, the right hand side is exactly the right hand side of the Stirling recurrence from (1). But, substituting from (1) doesn't match the solution for 
(2) which is 
$$\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}{k \choose j}{j^n}$$
$$\ne{k}{\sum_{j=1}^{k}{n \choose j}} - (k-1)\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}{{n-1} \choose j}-k$$

So what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to "show" that $S_{n, k} = P_{n, k}$, what about the _left-hand_ side?!

Comment: I'm not trying to show $S_{n,k} = P_{n,k}$, but derive the value for $S_{n,k}$ in terms of already known $P_{n,k}$. Now, the recurrence on the right is same as the recurrence of the Stirling on the right. My question is does that mean that the  $S_{n,k}  ?=  P_{n-1,k−1} + kP_{n−1,k}$? if not , how do I correctly get the expression for $S_{n,k}$ or can we even do that?. Thanks!

Comment: What is "the recurrence on the right"? A recurrence is an _equality_. I can compose a recurrence with the right-hand side you want using just _any_ $A_{n, k}$ in place of $S_{n, k}$ or $P_{n, k}$ if the left-hand side of it is completely out of question. I'm not even talking about the need to check the base of induction. To your main question... I don't think there's any simple relation between $S_{n, k}$ and $P_{n, k}$. If expected, I would look at their generating functions first, but these are too unrelated...